# Day/night cycle in Unity3D depending of the hour of the device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, cycle

Hello: I have seen lots of tutorials about day-night cycle in Unity,but I want something more concrete. I have searched a lot on the Internet but I didn't find nothing about this. I want to synchronize the sun cycle with the clock of my android device(i.e: smartphone).When it's 7 am in the clock,the sun will start to rise,and when it's 10 pm in the clock, the sun will start to go down. I can't find any script. Please,can you help me? Thanks. Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: [Source](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-get-system-time-in-unity.29667/#post-193308)

```
int sysHour = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
if(sysHour > 13)
Debug.Log("Afternoon");
else if(sysHour > 8)
Debug.Log("Morning");
else
Debug.Log("Night");
```

Comment: and day-night cycle : rotate directional light